# problems with the erf/erfc function in matlab

Tags: matlab, precision, numerical-methods

I am having problems with the accuracy of Matlab's `erf`/`erfc` functions.

As we know, `erf(x)` is only equal to 1 if `x` is infinity.

However, in Matlab, I am surprised that `erf(6)` is already equal to 1 and 6 is not even considerably large!

`erfc(x)` is a bit better in that `erfc(27)` is non-zero, whereas `erfc(28)` is zero.

Is there a way to improve the numerical performance of this function? I.e., increase the range of values for `erf(x)` to obtain a value that is not exactly 1? (and likewise 0 for `erfc`?)

Comment: how many digits of precision do you need? erf is providing 15 digits, erfc goes down to `e-300`. If you need more precision than that, you are probably using the function incorrectly

Comment: Do you have a reason to require such an accuracy for large values of the argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dealing with [double precision floating point](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). `erfc` performs differently because values are more closely spaced around 0 than 1. You need to represent your values with a different number system if you really need more precision (it's not clear to me why you would). Try using [variable precision arithmetic](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) if you have the Symbolic Math toolbox. Try

```
erf(vpa(6))
```

which returns the symbolic value `0.99999999999999997848026328750109`. You'll need to use [`digits`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/digits.html) as the argument gets larger. And of course if you convert the results back to floating point with [`double`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/double.html) you'll lose all of the extra precision.

Comment: unfortunately, I need to use the output of erf/erfc for optimization. I actually have to take the log of erfc. If the value of erfc is 0 then the optimization algorithm won't run.

Comment: @user1237300 In that case you might want to look at the exponentially scaled complementary error function `erfcx`.

Comment: @njuffa Is right. Try `x=30;` `log(erfcx(x))-x.^2` to implement `log(erfc(x))`. You can verify the result with `double(log(erfc(vpa(30))))`.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!!! I'm gonna try it out and hopefully I get better numerical stability.